# Check amount to words?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string onesPlace[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",};
    string thoseCrazyTeens[] = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen",};
    string tensPlace[] = {"twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety",};

    float userInput = 0;
    bool flag = true;
    cout << "Please input your check amount. " << endl;
    while (flag == true)
    {
        cin >> userInput;
        if (userInput > 100000)
        {
            cout << "That number is too big! Try again. " << endl;
            flag = true;
        }
        else
        {
            flag = false;
        }
    }

    int partOne = userInput;

    return 0;
}
```

Currently I'm working on this program that takes a user input (the check amount) and converts it from a numeric value to words up to 100000. An example of what I want to do would be for $344.67:

Three hundred forty four and 67/100.

I've got the string values for the words I'll need (hundred and thousand can come later for values over a certain amount), right now I'm trying to figure out how to get the cents after the decimal. If I use mod it's not always accurate.

After that, is there an easy way to blow through 1 to 20 without so many if statements?

Comment: merge your first 2 arrays of words and add "Zero" at the beginning. The numeric index will be the word in the array then

Answer (score 1):

To split a string out into dollars and cents, don't rely on code like `int partOne = userInput`.

In general, sscanf is the weapon of choice for parsing strings.  It's a C method, but it's more effective than the C++ alternatives.

So, something like this:

```
int dollars;
int cents;

int items = sscanf (userInput.c_str(), "$%d.%d", &dollars, &cents)
```

The value of *items* is used for error detection.  I highly suggest checking it.

As for handling cases 1 thru 20... *some* if statements will be necessary, but it shouldn't be onerous.  Just start coding and think about your algorithm as you go.

Answer (score 0):

mod is for integers not decimal numbers. If you want to use mode you would have to multiply the number by 100 and then mod it by 100.

Comment: Right, I was doing that, but it still results in rounding errors. 

Example: 100.45 yields 44 after multiplying by 100 and modding by 100.

Comment: that makes absolutely no since. I have no clue. 100.45 is 10045 and 10045 % 100 is 45. There should not be any rounding done at all.

Comment: Try it yourself, it is quite odd.

Comment: This is a good idea, but unfortunately, floating point numbers are not exact representations.  This is a broad abstraction, but the idea is the computer must represent ".45" as the sum of powers of two.  This is easy for integers, but not always possible for fractions.  Like ".45" is *approximately* 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/128 + 1/256 + 1/2048 + 1/4096, so in binary you might represent ".45" as `0.011100110011`, but that number is not EXACTLY right, which leads to rounding errors. You would need an infinite series to represent 0.45.  So... floats and doubles can't represent money.